# Semaphores task running in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have got following Java class. First task was to modify the classes to obtain ABCABCABCABC sequence, using threads which was quite simple. I simply did it by putting a.acquire b.realse inside A class, b.acquire c.release inside C class and c.acquire and a.relase.

Now, I have to modify the class to obtain 
ABBCABBC sequence, but I am struggling with that. Anyone knows how to deal with that?

Class code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class SemaphoresABC {

    private static final int COUNT = 10; //Number of letters displayed by threads
    private static final int DELAY = 5; //delay, in milliseconds, used to put a thread to sleep

    private static final Semaphore a = new Semaphore(1, true);
    private static final Semaphore b = new Semaphore(0, true);
    private static final Semaphore c = new Semaphore(0, true);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().start(); //runs a thread defined below 
        new B().start();
        new C().start();

    }

    private static final class A extends Thread { //thread definition

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                    //use semaphores here

                    System.out.print("A ");
                    //use semaphores here

                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Ooops...");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            System.out.println("\nThread A: I'm done...");
        }
    }

    private static final class B extends Thread {

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                    //use semaphores here

                    System.out.print("B ");
                    //use semaphores here

                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Ooops...");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            System.out.println("\nThread B: I'm done...");
        }
    }

    private static final class C extends Thread {

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                    //use semaphores here

                    System.out.print("C ");
                    //use semaphores here

                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Ooops...");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            System.out.println("\nThread C: I'm done...");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, some explanation why solution should be like yours, would come in handy. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop for `B` letter should be modified as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT * 2; i++) {

    b.acquire();

    System.out.print("B ");

    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        c.release();
    } else {
        b.release();
    }

    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
}
```

Here:

- `COUNT` is multiplied by two because the loop has to run twice as much, since `B` letter is printed twice.
- `i % 2` condition allows for releasing semaphore `C`, i.e proceeding, **every second** iteration.

Comment: Thank you, easier than I expected :)